# What is the image of at the beginning of Better Call Saul's next-to-last episode?

Tags: credits, better-call-saul

In the opening credits of the final episodes of *Better Call Saul's* final season, the usual title and grainy images of ash trays and foot massagers and matchbooks in urinals are increasingly interrupted by what appears to be the wearing out of the VHS tape that they are apparently recorded on.

In the next to last episode (S6 E12, "Waterworks"), this interference suddenly flashes to what appears to be the image of a person standing outdoors somewhere.

It is much too fast and unclear for me to make out.

Was anyone able to pause it just right and see what it is? Have the show's creators talked about what it was?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It’s a shot of Kim standing at the airport when she returns to Albuquerque, New Mexico later on in the same episode.

[image]

Screenshot comes from this YouTube video of the opening of *Better Call Saul* season 6, episode 12.

Answer (score 10):

Did you mean this? [image]

This is the best frame I can capture.

It looks like a women with her handbag standing outside and waiting.

My taking is:

- Before the intro starts, Saul asks Kim to come into his office so they can discuss their marriage.
- This lonely woman standing outside, she is either heading away or waiting outside. If she is heading away alone, it symbolises Kim is leaving Saul; if she is waiting outside, she is about to go into Saul office to discuss how their marriage ends.

It is really difficult to see what are in the background, they look like an airport.

Comment: +1 Yu Zhang. Giacomo's answer is a little better, but I appreciate this answer and the effort that went into it, as well.